# How is the Push Server selected for Progressive Web App notifications?

Tags: push-notification, progressive-web-apps

I've been trying to understand how Push Notifications work for Progressive Web Apps. One thing that I haven't seen clearly explained so far is the nature of the Push Server, as seen Here: [image: this image]

Precisely, I don't understand how the Push Server is chosen.

I've followed [this tutorial](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/codelabs/push-notifications#overview). The endpoint URL is generated by the Service Worker, but the Push Server isn't specified anywhere as far as I can tell.

So is it just specific to each web browser? Is it possible to make my own Push Server, or do I have to use one provided by Google?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question now that I understand this whole thing better :

The Push Server is imposed by the browser. It is a service provided by the editor of the browser (Google, Mozilla...), for the ease of the developer, but also as a mean to protect the users from spam. As such, it is not possible for a developer to use his own Push Server.